# Error when trying an additional SET command in query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1054

The MySQL query below works well as it is.  It replaces the field `votes_up` in a MySQL database with whatever value there is for the variable `$votes_up`.

```
UPDATE submission 
   SET votes_up = $votes_up 
 WHERE submissionid = $id
```

However, when I try to add a second condition that would simultaneously replace a field called `flag1` with the value of a variable called `$uflag`, I get an error message.  The query I'm trying to use for this is below.  The error message says `Unknown column 'admin' in 'field list'` if the value of `$uflag` is "admin".  Also, the value of `$uflag` is not being put into the database.  Any ideas why I am getting this error?

```
UPDATE submission
   SET votes_up = $votes_up, 
       flag1 = $uflag 
 WHERE submissionid = $id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add quotes to your string values:

```
UPDATE submission 
SET votes_up = $votes_up, flag1 = $uflag 
WHERE submissionid = $id
```

Should be:

```
UPDATE submission 
SET votes_up = $votes_up, flag1 = '$uflag' 
WHERE submissionid = $id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the query, first of all try:

```
UPDATE submission SET votes_up = '$votes_up', flag1 = '$uflag' WHERE submissionid = $id
```

If that doesn't work try to print the query and run it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around your values and escape them:

```
$sql = '
    UPDATE submission
    SET votes_up = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($votes_up).'",
        flag1 = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($uflag).'"
    WHERE submissionid = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($id).'"
';
```

The reason why it works with the other variable is, that for numbers quotes are not needed, however opening a huge security hole.

Comment: you code does not put quotes around the values as you are just concatenating the string with a function(s), you would still need to add a double quote like this:  flag1 = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($uflag).'"

Comment: Argh, was distracted. Edited.